# How to get the bit rate of existing MP3 or AAC in iOS?

Tags: ios, mp3, aac, bitrate, extaudiofile

I want to display the bitrate of existing MP3 files and AAC files to the user, but I don't know how to correctly extract the bitrate of these files.

So far, I've tried to get the `AudioConverterRef` pointer of the `ExtAudioFileRef` and then I wanted to get the bitrate out of the converter, but my problem starts already in the first step. I get `NULL` for the `kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioConverter` property:

```
    OSStatus status;
    AudioConverterRef result = NULL;

    UInt32 size = sizeof(result);
    status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioConverter, &size, &result);

    assert(status == noErr);

    assert(result != NULL); // here it fails
```

I can read the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` from the same `fileRef` successfully, so the `fileRef` is fine.

How to get the bitrate of compressed audio files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through the `AudioFileID` of an `ExtAudioFileRef`:

```
- (void) someMethod {
    ExtAudioFileRef extAudioFileRef = ...;  // init extAudioFileRef in some way

    AudioFileID audioFileId = [self getAudioFileID:extAudioFileRef];;
    UInt32 bitRate = [self getBitRate:audioFileId];
}

- (AudioFileID) getAudioFileID:(ExtAudioFileRef)fileRef {
    OSStatus status;
    AudioFileID result = NULL;

    UInt32 size = sizeof(result);
    status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_AudioFile, &size, &result);
    assert(status == noErr);

    return result;
}

- (UInt32) getBitRate:(AudioFileID)audioFileId {
    OSStatus status;
    UInt32 result = 0;

    UInt32 size = sizeof(result);
    status = AudioFileGetProperty(audioFileId, kAudioFilePropertyBitRate, &size, &result);
    assert(status == noErr);

    return result;
}
```